# Add/remove <receiver> depending on buildType

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have a `<receiver>` in AndroidManifest that I only want register when I build in `debug` buildType. I want "disable it" when I build in `release` mode.

Is that possible? At this moment, I have to comment/uncomment that part of AndroidManifest and it is pretty tedious.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478110/android-studio-two-flavors-with-different-manifest-files/28480064#28480064 it's meant to remove a `permission` from the manifest, but I'm sure you can use the same technique to remove a `receiver`

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. Just one question: can I use buildType instead of product flavours?

Comment: I would imagine yes. Hence a comment and not a direct answer. You test and let us know :)