# How to change the permission in the manifest based on the app flavor?

Tags: android, manifest, android-permissions, android-productflavors

I need to change the required permission of my app based on the app flavor. It's only one permission which should be replaced. How can i do it?

**Edit**

i'm releasing 2 version of my app for two different market. I'm using in app billing and the two market use different permission for the billing dialog so i need to use different permission to access the market's billing dialog.

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Edited.

Comment: Is it OK to ask for an unnecessary i leave the two permissions in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded my answer here:

[Android Studio two flavors with different manifest files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478110/android-studio-two-flavors-with-different-manifest-files#comment56364501_28480064)

create a new manifest based on the app flavor and add your flavor specific permission to it.. they will be merged.
[image]
[image]