# How to Fix in Flutter ? A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade > Android resource linking fai

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, android-manifest

I am getting errors when running the flutter app. My `AndroidManifest.xml` is like this:

Error:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade    >
> Android resource linking failed

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.my_app">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="my_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note I have `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M` in my gradle.properties that I have found in some another question.

Here is my [Error Log](https://pastebin.pl/view/27d7546c) on Paste Bin.

Comment: Hi! Please paste your full error log using https://pastebin.com

Comment: @JustInCoding It is off right now for me?

Comment: I think you should'nt post it in here.

Comment: Post your error log pls and not the xml code. (P.S. the last comment of mine was not supposed to be here sorry xD)